# Error while calling FCM backend service in server

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I deployed my Springboot in server, when I try to send a message to a specific user, the error says this..

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: oauth2.googleapis.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:108) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:995) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:429) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.17.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

But when I deployed in the cloud (Heroku) it works successfully. Please help.

I already checked my serviceAccount and properties, etc. It doesn't have a problem.

new ->

after opening the port in my server, i receive a new error message, it says

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:432) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.17.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.17.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.17.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.17.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseRequestInitializer.initialize(FirebaseRequestInitializer.java:55) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:88) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildPostRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:128) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendSingleRequest(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:148) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.send(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:126) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.0.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: Seems like some sort of certificate issue. Looks like your program isn't able to access the google APIs. Try checking along these lines.

Comment: you mean firebase certificate? i have an account in firebase, and already put the "serviceAccountKey" in my program. or my machine doesnt have certificate? @DerrylThomas

Comment: Nopes. Not firebase certificate. I think your machine doesn't have relevant client/ssl certificates to communicate with the google API. I do not have much knowledge wrt this, hence I added a few new tags that might help get it to the right audience.

Comment: ahhhh i see... yes, my server is http, not https. looks like its because i dont have a ssl. btw, thanks for your help, man. :D

Comment: UnknownHostException implies your DNS server doesn't know about Googleapis.com

Comment: By the way, non android code shouldn't be using guava-26.0-android (i.e. Firebase's Java sdk is meant to be used in conjunction with the Android SDK, not OpenJDK)

Comment: now the new error is Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
. what is this?